# Go's sync.Map load result could not be added

Tags: go

I just wanted to do some simple CREATE or ADD on sync.Map

```
gore> :import sync
gore> var sm sync.Map
gore> sm.Store(12345,1)
gore> result, ok := sm.Load(12345)
1
true
gore> newr := result +1
# command-line-arguments
/var/folders/kl/n95_c8j15wn1784jmsq08mq80000gn/T/112740772/gore_session.go:21:17: invalid operation: result + 1 (mismatched types interface {} and int)
error: exit status 2
exit status 2
```

`result` is `1` on the repl ,but it couldn't be added with `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
>
> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

---

The error message tells all:

```
invalid operation: result + 1 (mismatched types interface {} and int)
```

Use a type assertion on `result` type `interface {}` for `int`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var sm sync.Map
    sm.Store(12345, 1)
    result, ok := sm.Load(12345)
    fmt.Println(result, ok)
    newr := result.(int) + 1
    fmt.Println(newr)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qotBVR4fSNV

Output:

```
1 true
2
```